# parse xml for creating inserts in postgresql

Tags: xml, postgresql

I've been given a task of creating the mechanism of transforming hierarchical data from postres relational table to xml and back. Whilst I had not much trouble converting table data to xml, I am stuck in converting actual xml to multiple inserts. With the documentation that is provided with postgres I could do nothing(. Any help would be appreciated.

Example of xml (independent Button element and Grid with children):

```
<BTN>
    806
    <BTN_WINDOW />
</BTN>
<GRID>
    217
    <GRID_COLUMNS>
        <GRDCOL visible="true" vl_order="0"
            description="some description">
            <vl_props>some info</vl_props>
            <vl_params>some info</vl_svc_params>
            226
        </GRDCOL>
        <GRDCOL visible="true" vl_order="1"
            title="some description">
            <vl_props>some info</vl_props>
            <vl_params_1>some info</vl_svc_params>
            218
        </GRDCOL>
        <GRDCOL visible="true" vl_order="2" title="some description">
            <vl_props>some info</vl_props>
            <vl_svc_params>some info</vl_svc_params>
            219
        </GRDCOL>
        <GRDCOL visible="true" vl_order="3"
            title="some description">
            <vl_props>some info</vl_props>
            <vl_params>some info</vl_svc_params>
            220
        </GRDCOL>
     </GRID_COLUMNS>
</GRID>
```

After parsing xml I am to generate insert statement for button with id 806
        
            806

```
INSERT INTO TABLE (ID, PARENT_ID,POSITION_IN_PARENT) VALUES (806,NULL,NULL)
```

Then I am to generate a series of inserts of GRID and its columns (GRDCOL),

```
  <GRID>
    217
    <GRID_COLUMNS>
        <GRDCOL visible="true" vl_order="0"
            description="some description">
            <vl_props>some info</vl_props>
            <vl_params>some info</vl_svc_params>
            226
        </GRDCOL>
        <GRDCOL visible="true" vl_order="1"
            title="some description">
            <vl_props>some info</vl_props>
            <vl_params_1>some info</vl_svc_params>
            218
        </GRDCOL>
        <GRDCOL visible="true" vl_order="2" title="some description">
            <vl_props>some info</vl_props>
            <vl_svc_params>some info</vl_svc_params>
            219
        </GRDCOL>
        <GRDCOL visible="true" vl_order="3"
            title="some description">
            <vl_props>some info</vl_props>
            <vl_params>some info</vl_svc_params>
            220
        </GRDCOL>
     </GRID_COLUMNS>
</GRID>

INSERT INTO TABLE (ID, PARENT_ID,POSITION_IN_PARENT) 
VALUES (217,NULL,NULL) --grid itself
INSERT INTO TABLE (ID, PARENT_ID, POSITION_IN_PARENT) 
VALUES (226,217,GRID_COLUMNS)   
INSERT INTO TABLE (ID, PARENT_ID, POSITION_IN_PARENT) 
VALUES (218,217,GRID_COLUMNS)
INSERT INTO TABLE (ID, PARENT_ID, POSITION_IN_PARENT) 
VALUES (219,217,GRID_COLUMNS)
INSERT INTO TABLE (ID, PARENT_ID, POSITION_IN_PARENT) 
VALUES (220,217,GRID_COLUMNS)
```

I can not figure out the way to traverse through each node in xml and generate inserts with Postgres only. Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please take the [tour], read [ask], and post a [mcve].  This question is too broad.

Comment: My bad, made some edits. Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I came across is quite straightforward.

Firstly we find out how many children are there in current xml.

```
SELECT btrim(xpath('count(./*)',
                     p_input_xml,
                     ARRAY [ ARRAY [ 'el',
                     'http://example.com' ],
                     array [ 'p',
                     'http://example1.com' ] ]) ::text,
               '{}')
    into v_child_count;
```

Then we iterate through children and then recursively we find the children of the children and so on. Thus we shred the xml into smaller xml.

```
select replace(btrim(xpath(format('./*[%s]', CURRENT_CHILD_ID),
                               p_input_xml,
                               ARRAY [ ARRAY [ 'el',
                               'http://example.com' ] ]) ::text,
                         '"{}"'),
                   '\"',
                   '"') ::xml
      into v_child_xml;
```

Answer (score 0):

Parsing XML document is little bit harder then generating. But it is possible.

You can use `XPATH` function - it is enough fast and good for large documents too.

For document like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1250"?>
<enprimeur>
        <vino>
            <id>1</id>
            <nazev>Alter Ego de Palmer</nazev>
            <vyrobce>63</vyrobce>
            <rocnik>2012</rocnik>
            <cena0375>0</cena0375>
            <cena1500>0</cena1500>
            <cena3000>0</cena3000>
            <cena6000>0</cena6000>
            <cena0750>1425</cena0750>
            <cenastart>1085</cenastart>
            <min0375>0</min0375>
            <min0750>0</min0750>
            <odrudy>51 % Merlot, 40 % Cabernet Sauvignon,9 % Petit Verdot</odrudy>
            <bestin>2017 - 2026</bestin>
            <klas>2</klas>
            <sklad0375>0</sklad0375>
            <sklad0750>0</sklad0750>
            <sklad1500>0</sklad1500>
            <sklad3000>0</sklad3000>
            <sklad6000>0</sklad6000>
            <alk>13,4 %</alk>
            <remark>Premiant oblasti Margaux Ch. Palmer tentokrát ve svých obou vínech tì.il z dokonale zralého Merlotu, kterého do svých smìsí naládova
            <rating>Robert Parker: /100
TOPVINO SCORE: 92-94/100
James Suckling: 92-93/100
Wine Spectator: 90-93/100</rating>
            <zalozeno></zalozeno>
            <rozloha></rozloha>
            <stari></stari>
            <puda></puda>
            <produkce></produkce>
            <zrani></zrani>
            <active>1</active>
            <stitky>
            <stitek>8</stitek>
            <stitek>1</stitek>
            </stitky>
        </vino>
        <vino>
  ...
```

You can use q query:

```
select x[1]::int id, x[2] nazev, x[3] vyrobce,
       x[4]::int rocnik, x[5]::double precision cena0375,
       x[6]::double precision cena1500, x[7]::double precision cena3000,
       x[7]::double precision cena6000, x[8]::double precision cena0750,
       x[9]::double precision cenastart, x[10]::double precision min0375,
       x[11]::double precision min0750, x[12] alk, x[13] klas
  from (select xpath('/vino/id/text()|'
'/vino/nazev/text()|/vino/vyrobce/text()|/vino/rocnik/text()|'
'/vino/cena0375/text()|/vino/cena1500/text()|/vino/cena3000/text()|'
'/vino/cena6000/text()|/vino/cena0750/text()|/vino/cenastart/text()|'
'/vino/min0375/text()|/vino/min0750/text()|/vino/alk/text()|'
'/vino/klas/text()', v)::text[] x 
          from (select unnest(xpath('/enprimeur/vino', d)) from xmldata) g(v)) s;
```

Comment: Thank you, but in my case xml is formeddynamically I do not know its structure beforehand.

Comment: @Vad Boro, How can you parse a document whose structure is not known?